# How to talk about writers we love

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to ask as to which words can be used when we talk about the artists whose works we love and respect  ?
For example what can be replaced with the verb love when I say :

> I love Dostoevsky.

What I mean here is I love his works or books, not him as  personally even his personality which I have no chance to know.

In my opinion, the word *love* does not sound too bad in the sentence above because he lived many years ago and when we say "I love Dostoevsky" people will understand what I mean.
But when we use this sentence for writers or singers who are still alive, the sentence's meaning become ambiguous.

For example :

> I love Adele or I admire Adele

with these sentences people may infer I love her personality or appearance.

Which words would  native speakers use when they talk about writers they love to read

Comment: It's perfectly fine to say "I love [artist's] [what they do]". I love Adele's songs. I love J.K. Rowling's books.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you're over-thinking this a little bit. English would be effectively unusable if it were not for the ability to implicitly understand expressions in context.

Let me give an opposite example. If I visit my tax accountant, and come out and say to a friend "I'm stuffed", it would imply that I am likely to be facing a large tax bill. If, on the other hand, I visit a particularly good steakhouse and come out and say "I'm stuffed", it would imply that I had perhaps over-indulged in the 285 gram Victoria fillet and garlic potato mash. Even though exactly the same expression is used in both cases I would have no need to distinguish between the two of them since the meaning is obvious (at least to an Australian) from the context. Nor, obviously, would I need to explain that "When I say 'stuffed', I am not referring to myself having undergone the process of taxidermy".

Similarly, there are millions of people around the world who would be familiar with Adele's work. But as with most people, the ones who know her, both well and personally, would be likely to be somewhere in double or low triple digits. Consequently if you were to say to me that you "love Adele" I would take it to mean, just on statistical probability alone, that you love her work because it is HIGHLY improbable that you know the woman herself. I have no reason to believe that she isn't loveable, but I have a strong reason to believe that ***you*** don't know her well enough to know whether she is and that therefore your statement is about what you ***do*** know about her. And that is, her body of work. (My interpretation may obviously be different if I knew that you saw her on a daily basis and in such a case clarification would be useful.)

I can say that I love *The Killer Angels*. But since reasonably well balanced individuals can't develop romantic attachments to literary works, it's pretty obvious what I'm referring to. I can say that I love Dr. Richard A Gabriel, but since neither moustaches nor Y chromosomes are my thing (and again because it's highly unlikely that we've ever met, and we haven't) it's pretty obvious that I'm referring to his works like *Scipio Africanus: Rome's Greatest General* or *Man and Wound in the Ancient World: A History of Military Medicine from Sumer to the Fall of Constantinople*, and not to the man himself. The fact that he is still (I hope) alive makes no difference because again, context is king. Similarly I "love" both Hemingway and F Scott Fitzgerald despite the fact that as people, based on what I've read of them, I'm not sure that I would have even liked them had I met them in person courtesy of a time machine.

As Ronald suggested, to avoid ambiguity you could always append the word "work". "I love Adele's work" (or "songs", or "albums", or, in the case of writers, "writing") allows no room for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can say:

> 'I am a passionate fan of *Leonardo da Vinci's* work.'